# Adding CreatedOn column for changeset links in work item links tab

Tags: tfs, changeset, workitem

The links tab of a work item in TFS 2010 shows links to changesets associated with that work item. 
The tab is generally designed to show links to other work items so, for a changeset, only the "title" and "comment" columns are shown. When you try to add more columns, only work item columns are listed.

I want to see changeset's "CreatedOn" and "By User" fields in the links tab. Is there a way I can add these columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changesets will only be listed by title.  Linked items direclty inside of TFS support the additonal columns such as "Create Date" and "Created By".  When you export this data to Excel, for example, changesets are not even listed.  When you checkin changes those checkins are aggregated to a single entity called a "Changeset"  Changesets have a title, description and linktype.  Since a developer, for example, would never create a changeset but rather TFS would create one for him, the identity that TFS runs under would always be listed as the *By User*.

*CreatedOn* could yield useful information though which you can probably display creating a custom control through [TFS API](http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/).  Take a look at the linked page which will give you an example of how you could go about doing this type of modification.  I have never had to do this though so I can't say with 100% confidence that it is possible but if it is- TFS API via Custom Controls would be your best bet.